# Showing $T(\mathbf{v})$ is an eigenvector of S

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$, $S,T\in{\mathscr{L}(V)}$, and assume $ST=TS$.  If $\mathbf{v}\in{V}$ is an eigenvector of S with eigenvalue $\lambda$, prove $T(\mathbf{v})$ is also an eigenvector of $S$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

I'm new to the advanced linear stuff and having trouble getting started.  So I can go as far as this.
Since $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of S, then $S(\mathbf{v})=\lambda\mathbf{v}$.  And that is where I don't know where to go from.

Comment: You know that ST=TS, so what happens when you do $T(S(\mathbf{v})$?

Comment: Oh okay, I think I can see it...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: We have

$$S(T(v)) = TS(v) = T(\lambda v) = \lambda T(v)$$

Can you justify every step?

Comment: @Irish M Powers, understand what T Bongers is saying here.  Do you know the justification for each move?

Comment: Well, it looks like we know since ST=TS we can make the first move, and since T is a linear transformation and lambda a scalar we can pull it out, right?

Comment: @IrishMPowers Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2):

So you know $S(\mathbf{v})=\lambda\mathbf{v}.$  Then
$$T(S(\mathbf{v}))=T(\lambda\mathbf{v})=\lambda{T}(\mathbf{v})$$
So $TS(\mathbf{v})=ST(\mathbf{v})=\lambda{T}(\mathbf{v})$

Thus, you can see that by the definitions of eigenvalue and eigenvector, $T(\mathbf{v})$ is an eigenvector of S, and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: That was easier than I thought.